# Using pgfplots and gnuplot and compiling with output-directory

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I would like to use the `pgfplots` package along with `gnuplot`. However, I cannot get this to work if I compile using the `-output-directory` option. For example, if I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot gnuplot{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If this is saved as `test.tex` and I compile with `lualatex -shell-escape test.tex`, it works fine. However, if I try to change the output directory, such a compiling with `lualatex -shell-escape -output-directory=.. test.tex`, then `pgfplots` cannot find the file `test.pgf-plot.table` which contains the `gnuplot` output. (The output directory `..` was just to make this example as simple as possible.)

Is there a way to patch the command that reads `gnuplot` output to search for the file in the output directory instead of the current working directory?

Comment: Just my view ignore it: I usually avoid `-output-directory` when using gnuplottex,pstool -shell-escape applications due to foldernames,paths,synctex, etc...

Comment: Having the same problem, I've investigated a bit. The call to gnuplot is in the function pgfplotgnuplot in the file tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex. The path of the corresponding files is based on \pgfplots@plot@filename in tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex; open questions: (1) how do we find out what -output-directory latex was run with? (2) should we make that directory gnuplot's CWD?

Comment: See also [pdftex - Access value of -output-directory - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294931/access-value-of-output-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1) to get the value of `-output-directory` instead of hard coding it.

Answer (score 6):

Digging around in the files, mentioned in @anonymous' comment, to find out what to patch, I spotted the following pgf-key. It can simply be overwritten in the preamble of the document.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/plot/gnuplot call={cd build && gnuplot}}
```

Here the build directory is called 'build' and can of course be changed at your needs. The command concatenation `&&` should work for Windows and Unix. While being the Unix syntax it works without complaining in Windows (tested).

Comment: Apart from hard coding the path like this it's also possible to  ■ put the path in an environment variable, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136137/250119 or ■ access value of output-directory, see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294931/250119