# output-directory and shell commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, shell-escape

Let's use a small example to use `gnuplot` to draw a nice function using `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[domain=-3:3,samples=100] function {sin(x)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I compile (using `pdflatex` or `xelatex`) it with `--shell-escape`, no problem.

BUT, if I compile with `-ouput-directory=`**path**, with **path** different from current directory with only the file`.tex`, it does not work (except if you previously compile it in current directory and keep some intermediate files).

I want to use the `gnuplot` functions of `tikz`, and I need to have separate output dir. How can I say to `pgf/tikz` that it can find the output files of gnuplot in the right directory ?

**EDIT**

I realized the problem comes from the file

`..../texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex` on line 347 :

```
\immediate\pgfutil@write18{gnuplot \pgf@plotgnuplotfile}%
```

So it calls gnuplot without taking into account the fact that the file `.gnuplot` is not in current directory but in output directory. I juste don't know how to specify the output directory in this line. Is there a macro that contains the path of the output directory ?

**EDIT 2** : I realized someone asked the same last question in 2011, and did not get a proper answer (only for luatex) on [a mailing list](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2011-September/008769.html). Does it mean there is no standard solution for pdflatex ?

**EDIT 3** : I have the same problem with the package minted, so I wonder now if it's possible to use shell-escape commands and output-directory in the same time !

**EDIT 4** : I just realized that someone asked the very same question on SE on [using-pgfplots-and-gnuplot-and-compiling-with-output-directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109331/using-pgfplots-and-gnuplot-and-compiling-with-output-directory) and did not get a proper answer as well.

Comment: How do you compile pgfplots codes which have a gnuplot option? I am a windows user.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I'm sorry, I'm not a windows user :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using pgfplots and gnuplot and compiling with output-directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109331/using-pgfplots-and-gnuplot-and-compiling-with-output-directory)

Answer (score 1):

I add this answer to my own question, if someone got the same problem as me, but this is not a good answer, and I will not accept it.

I decided to use an environment variable that contains the output directory. I can retrieve the content of this variable into LaTeX (using [this solution for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/can-i-access-system-environment-variables-from-latex-for-instance-home), but you need to use an absolute path for temporary files for the XeTeX version) and use it to patch the macros (in pgf for example) that need a patch to work with --output-directory.

This is not a good way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Assuming i have the path: How to patch what to get it working?

Comment: The path is mentioned at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444407/250119