# Possible Issues of using -output-directory

Tags: pdftex, texlive, auxiliary-files

As I am considering using `-output-directory=<some/path>` to reduce clutter in my working directory, I am wondering what are the known problems with this approach.

The ones I am aware of are:

- pdf file needs to be copied back
- synctex won't work unless the appropriate files are copied back to the working directory.

Are there others?

In composing my earlier question [Access value of -output-directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294931/access-value-of-output-directory), I came across [output-directory and shell commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136012/output-directory-and-shell-commands) which seems to imply that there is an issue with using `gnuplot`. As that question was only answered by the OP I am not sure if there is an easy fix to that problem.

Comment: Just a comment. If you are using MiKTeX, you can also specify a directory for auxiliary files by using the `-aux-directory` argument.

Comment: The `Trash AUX Files` (at least in TeXShop) won't work as the aux files are no longer in the same directory as the .tex.

Comment: I tried with MacOS and Python but I can't specify the right path.. any clue?
--->  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468278/how-to-use-output-directory-with-python-subprocess-call-and-macos