# Access value of -output-directory

Tags: pdftex, texlive, auxiliary-files

I am considering using the command line option `-output-directory=<some/path>` so that the temporary files do not clog my working directory but are also available for subsequent builds.  This will also eliminate a lot of unnecessary Dropbox activity.

However, I also produce some temporary files of my own, so would like to be able to access what the `output-directory` was specified as on the command line.

So, in the MWE below, how do I set the value of the macro `\OuptutDirectory` so that I can correctly determine the names of my temporary files?

### References:

- [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files)
- [Is there a way to configure pdflatex to make all but the .tex and .pdf files hidden files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87816/is-there-a-way-to-configure-pdflatex-to-make-all-but-the-tex-and-pdf-files-hid)

### Related Question:

- [Possible Issues of using -output-directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294934/possible-issues-of-using-output-directory)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\OuptutDirectory{????}% <--- How do I determine this?

\edef\MyTempFile{\OuptutDirectory/\jobname.foo}%

\begin{document}
    My temp file is \MyTempFile.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a variable in `pdftex` that keeps the value of the output directory.

Comment: As a kind of workaround you can set `openout_a` or something to write to any directories (for example `/tmp/`) then hard code it; or use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513810/250119 -- scontents to not use temporary file at all.

Comment: @user202729: Thanks for the link to the `scontents` pacakge. I wasn not aware of that package.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707152/programmatically-get-the-output-directory?noredirect=1#comment1764544_707152

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up, in a working directory, the file `a.tex` containing

```
\newwrite\test
\immediate\openout\test=temp.txt

\immediate\write\test{Hello}

\bye
```

I created a `temp` subdirectory and called

```
pdftex -output-dir=temp a
```

and the `temp.txt` file was created in the `temp` directory:

```
> ls -R .
a.tex   temp/

./temp:
a.log       temp.txt
```

There's no variable that can be accessed from within `pdftex` that holds the output directory path, as far as I know.

Of course you can emulate it by passing the definition of `\OutputDirectory` from the command line:

```
pdftex -output-dir=temp "\def\OutputDirectory{./temp}\input a"
```

Comment: So that explains why some of my temp files were in the temp directory and not others -- I was using `\immediate\write18` and getting the shell to create some related files.  I  guess I'lll use the "emulate" solution... As always, thanks - much appreciated.

Comment: The last line is a gem luring the newbies into the programming side of TeX. Thanks, @egreg !

Comment: @LovesProbability Even better: if you define an environment variable `TEMPDIR`, you can call `pdftex -output-dir=$TEMPDIR "\def\OutputDirectory{./$TEMPDIR}\input a"`, so this is scriptable.

Answer (score 4):

### New solution starting from TeX Live 2024 (`$TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`)

Just access the environment variable named `$TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`.
Use `sys_get_shell`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62032/250119 .
Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707351/250119 .

---

### Solution using `currfile-abspath`

Using `currfile-abspath` detailed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54894/250119
(see the note regarding `-recorder` flag), it's possible to use `\currfileabsdir` to get the output directory, using the facts that

- Writing to a file will write it to the output directory by default
- `\input` searches in the current `-output-directory` first

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% write the content to a temporary file `test.tex`
\iow_new:N \myfile
\iow_open:Nn \myfile {test.tex}
\iow_now:Nn \myfile {
    \tl_set:Nx \myoutputdir {\currfileabsdir}
}
\iow_close:N \myfile

% execute the content of that file
\input {test.tex}

% print the obtained output directory path to the PDF
\texttt{\myoutputdir}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

It does require a temporary file, however.

**Note** that if in one compilation there is `-recorder`, then in the following compilation there's no `-recorder`, I think it's impossible to detect the change --
`currfile-abspath` package gets it wrong as well.
Attempting to write to `\jobname.fls` might do something, but on Windows I think multiple write to the same file is not allowed.
One option is to randomize the file name, but that does not work on MiKTeX (recorder file not updated online) and clutters the file system.

**Note** that you may want to rename `test.tex` to something sufficiently obscure, and possibly check if the file exists before writing. If you're not careful you might overwrite some important file.

---

### Alternative using `ps` to get current process's command-line arguments

(because of some permission issue this does not work on Overleaf, but otherwise should work on most POSIX systems)

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_get_shell:nnN {ps~-o~args=~-p~$(ps~-o~ppid=~-p~$$)} {\cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab} \l_data_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then `\l_data_tl` consist of the command-line of the TeX process (e.g. `pdflatex --output-directory=/a/b/c main.tex`)
but note that all the characters will have "other" catcode including spaces.

From this, parsing the string to get the output directory is a standard exercise. Note that the relevant flag might be written as...

```
-output-d=/path
-output-d=
-output-dir=/path
--output-dir=/path
--output-directory=/path
-output-d /path
-output-directory /path
--output-directory /path
```

As far as I can tell these are all the variants (all prefixes of `output-directory` longer than or equal to `output-d` are accepted), although I haven't checked with e.g. `texdoc pdftex-changes`.

---

### Another alternative using `find` to look for the log file

Refer to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707153/250119). Not recommended.

---

### Another alternative

(completely untested)

if you don't have `-recorder`, first write the file then refer to [How to obtain absolute path of a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650955/250119) (or maybe `file_get_full_name` function in expl3, I'm not sure) to get the path of the file. (although this might fail, output-directory is not necessarily searched in by kpsewhich)

---

Related answers:

- If you only need to read the file from TeX (instead of an external command) normal `\file_get:nnN` or `\input` works.
- If the output directory is in an environment variable (see [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294931/access-value-of-output-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1214489_294935)),
  you don't need to pass the output directory in a command, it's also possible to [read the environment variable directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136137/250119).
- For LuaTeX there's a direct solution: [In Luatex, how to know effective output directory?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388326/250119)
- Hard code both the path to write the file to and the path to read the file from (requires `openout_any=a` environment variable)
- Use `scontents` so you don't need a temporary file at all, refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513810/250119

Comment: See [document configuration - Placing temporary files outside of dropbox for compilation: issues with openout_any and nomenclature - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37822/placing-temporary-files-outside-of-dropbox-for-compilation-issues-with-openout) for `openout_any=a`, and also [(How) can I include the file somedir/file.tex in the file somedir/subdir/anotherfile.tex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-can-i-include-the-file-somedir-file-tex-in-the-file-somedir-subdir-another) and

Comment: [filesystem access - Write to a file outside of the current folder - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427018/write-to-a-file-outside-of-the-current-folder) .

Comment: && with shell escape using `ps` would work (operating system specific) → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661245/250119

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62010/250119