# epstopdf package fails when graphics to be included is inside output-directory

Tags: includegraphics, eps, epstopdf, output-directory

To reproduce the error:

1. Create `b.eps` file that contains anything. For example, the following command will create `b.eps`:

   ```
   asy -noV -o b -c 'draw((0, 0)--(1, 1));'
   ```
2. Create folder `./d/`, put `b.eps` to it.
3. Create `./a.tex` in the current directory with content:

   ```tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \graphicspath{{d/}}
   \includegraphics{b}
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape --recorder --output-directory=d/ a.tex`.
5. See error.

---

I believe the error happens because: when the graphics is in the output directory, LaTeX is unable to correctly determine the path to the `.eps` file relative to the current directory,
in order to pass to `epstopdf` --- consequently, it cannot be converted to `pdf`.

Is it possible for this issue to be fixed?

---

As a workaround, it is possible to explicitly specify the path to the graphics:

```
\includegraphics{d/b}
```

But I'd like to know if there's a proper solution as well.

The context is that I'm using `asypictureB` package with some patches to make it work with arbitrary `--output-directory`,
and the `.asy` file is of course created in `output-directory`, which makes the `.eps` also generated there.

Comment: `--output-directory` complicates almost every aspect of tex processing, simply not using it is always my recommendation

Comment: although I gather that texlive2024 will have an environment setting so that external programs know if this has been used and what it is set to so it would at least be possible to configure then to find files that have been hidden in this way

Comment: Unfortunately because [it's very difficult to automatically determine value of `output-directory`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294931/250119), most packages (that involves shell-escape) does not support `output-directory` different from the current directory, and consequently it's poorly supported nowadays.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707351/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, we should merge that question with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294931/250119 (there are good answers there too) (but merging requires diamond moderator)

Comment: flag it and summon Joseph:-)

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found